# SQL not updating multiple databases...whats wrong with my sql?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm trying to run one SQL command to update multiple databases.  If I copy 'n paste sql code below directly into PHPMYADMIN it executes just fine, but when I run the sql through php it doesn't update?

If I run the updates for each database separately via my php script they both update fine, so I'm confused?

What am I doing wrong?

SQL Code:

```
UPDATE rst.users a, rst.user_type b 
SET a.first_name='Timsd',a.last_name='Lebaronsd',a.password='timsd',
 a.email='tim@dog.comsd', a.user_type_id='5',a.language_code='en_US', 
   a.timezone='Pacific/Midway', create_ts = '2010-07-16 12:33:31' 
WHERE a.user_type_id = b.user_type_id AND b.account_id = 1 AND a.users_id = 90; 

use externalusers; 

UPDATE externalusers.user 
SET fullname="'Timsd' 'Lebaronsd'", emailaddress="'tim@dog.comsd'" 
WHERE rst_id = 90 AND rst_account_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_query() and similar functions can't execute multiple statements for security reasons.
Use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://uphp.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) if you really want to execute multiple statements with single call.

P.S. It's not a PHP feature, but a feature of mysql C API.

Comment: Could I place the SQL inside a stored procedure, then in the 1st sql statement call the stored procedure that would do the update to the other database?

Comment: Ok, I dumped the stored procedures idea and decided to implement the mysqli solution.  Works great now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a security feature that prevents you from executing multiple queries with a single mysql_query() call. Unfortunately there's no way around it with the native mysql_* functions.

However I believe you can do it if you use PDO or MySQLi. I highly recommend PDO.

Comment: Could I place the SQL inside a stored procedure, then in the 1st sql statement call the stored procedure that would do the update to the other database?

Comment: you could or you could make two database connections.

Answer (score 0):

To add to answers from others its important to say that you are not actually executing a single SQL statement but 2 (or actually probably 3), one after the other.  PHPMYADMIN is simply breaking them on ; and executing them in sequence.